# Como identificar no construtor o método que foi chamado?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Como faço para no ***construtor*** do meu `controller` identificar qual método foi chamado?

Estou utilizando o `Laravel 5.3` e meu `controller` segue o padrão `resource` (`index, show, edit`...).

Comment: Só uma questão? Porque precisas que isso aconteça?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No arquivos de rotas, está configurado:

```
Route::get('/paginas', 'PaginasController@index');
```

e no ***construtor*** utilize:

```
$controlerAndAction = \Route::currentRouteAction();
```

saída:

```
string(44) "App\Http\Controllers\PaginasController@index"
```

---

***ou***

```
$controlerAndAction = \Route::current()->getActionName();
```

saída:

```
string(44) "App\Http\Controllers\PaginasController@index"
```

---

Para pegar o `action` que no caso é o `index` uma função como essa resolve:

```
$actionName = function ($value)
{
   return substr($value, strrpos($value, '@') + 1 );
};
echo $actionName($controlerAndAction);
```

<sub>Não vi nada na documentação de forma direta, até tem um `getAction` mas, não traz direto a ação (`Action`) e muitas vezes dependendo da configuração da rota (`Route`) traz **nulo** o seu valor.</sub>